# if a chicken has been in the freezer from November 18 till now July 2 is it safe to cook it and eat it?

Tags: chicken

if a chicken has been in the freezer from November 18 till now July 2 is it safe to cook it and eat it??I'm old and I don't understand

Comment: Some additional information would be helpful to answer this question: What temperature was it stored at? Did you buy it already frozen or froze a fresh chicken? Is it a whole chicken or just parts of it? Is it rather fat or not so much?

Answer (score 1):

Frozen foods will remain safe for a very long time, provided that they were treated with care before being frozen.  If your chicken was kept refrigerated before freezing and frozen before spoilage, or purchased frozen...AND, you thaw it in a safe manner (in the refrigerator is best), it will be safe to cook and eat. Freezer temperature matters, as does the temperature cycling that most home freezers do to maintain a "frost free" environment. This impacts quality, rather than safety. In the end, it is more likely that the quality has degraded, especially if it is not vacuum packaged.  A lot depends on the packaging.  There is a good chance that it has freezer burn (dehydration); with that comes the potential of off-flavors and textures.  However, that is not a safety issue.